# Cannot parse datetime using strptime

Tags: python, numpy, strptime

I am trying to load data from csv and display it in a matplotlib scatter graph, where on X axis I have formatted datetime. This is the data:

```
0,03/12/2017 21:00:00.000 +0000,4745
0,03/12/2017 22:00:00.000 +0000,3046
0,03/12/2017 23:00:00.000 +0000,2052
0,03/13/2017 00:00:00.000 +0000,1455
2,03/13/2017 00:00:00.000 +0000,2
1,03/13/2017 00:00:00.000 +0000,2
```

And the Python3.4 code I use:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

retries, count = np.loadtxt(open('search-results.csv', 'r'),
                  delimiter=",",
                  skiprows=1,
                  unpack=True,
                  usecols=[0, 2])

time = np.loadtxt(open('search-results.csv', 'r'),
                  delimiter=",",
                  skiprows=1,
                  unpack=True,
                  usecols=[1],
                  dtype=str)

dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(str(d), "b'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.000 +0000'") for d in time]

plt.scatter(dates, retries, s=count)
plt.grid(which='both', color='#aaaaaa')
plt.savefig('out.png', format='png')
```

When I run the above code it looks like it is parsing the data until it reaches day 13:

```
ValueError: time data "b'03/13/2017 00:00:00.000 +0000'" does not match format "b'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.000 +0000'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

You should change the following line from this:

```
dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(str(d), "b'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.000 +0000'") for d in time]
```

to this:

```
dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(str(d), "b'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.000 +0000'") for d in time]
```

---

Well the error you are getting is correct, because you are telling your code to expect a date, formated as: `"b'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.000 +0000'"` but you are passing it a date formated like this:

```
"b'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.000 +0000'" (interchanged month and date).
```

Your code works for the first 3 lines because 12 is in the Month range of a Year, but when it gets 13 on the 4th line it breaks!

Good luck :)

Comment: Yeah , I need to take a break :-)

Comment: Seems so mate :)